# Adding Message under Payment Method (like paypal redirect message)

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, messages

I need to add message under Redsys Payment Method (like paypal redirect message) when you click it.
Example:
[image: Now => Need]

Where i can add this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically that depends first of all on the payment module you are using. Since I don't know what that module does or not, I'll 
tell you how that messages work in general.

A payment module usually has a Block which inherits from `Mage_Payment_Block_Form` (usually you find a `Form.php` somewhere in  the `Block` folder of the payment module).
In this block there is the possibility to call a method `setMethodLabelAfterHtml()` which sets the message for the specific payment method (that's usually done in the constructor).

For example adding this line in the constructor of the Form Block of your payment method, look for the corresponding block and add the message `$this->setMethodLabelAfterHtml('You will be reirected to...');`
in the constructor.

> Please note: If you have a third party module which receives updates it's not recommended to make changes in their code. I've only tried to explain you how the message for payment methods are working.